# Getting "ScreenCaptureError" in Chrome using Kurento Media Server

Tags: javascript, webrtc, kurento, screensharing

I'm trying to share my screen with Kurento WebRtc server. But getting this error:

```
NavigatorUserMediaError {name: "ScreenCaptureError", message: "", constraintName: ""}
```

There is no errors in Firefox with same code.
Constraints using for webrtc:

```
    var constraints = {
        audio: true,
        video: {
            mandatory : {
                chromeMediaSource: 'screen',
                maxWidth: 1920,
                maxHeight: 1080,
                maxFrameRate: 30,
                minFrameRate: 15,
                minAspectRatio: 1.6
            },
            optional: []
        }
    }

    var options = {
           localVideo : video,
           onicecandidate : onIceCandidate,
           mediaConstraints : constraints
    }
    webRtcPeer = new kurentoUtils.WebRtcPeer.WebRtcPeerSendonly(options,function(error) {
       if (error) {
           return console.error(error);
       }
       webRtcPeer.generateOffer(onOfferPresenter);
    });
```

How do I share my screen using chrome and kurento?

Comment: Chrome can only share screen through a Chrome Extension. Which one are you using?

Comment: I'm using extension by [Muaz Khan](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/)

Comment: @igracia, I just can't find a way how to use extension with kurento

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sharing a screen with Kurento through WebRTC, is exactly the same as sharing the webcam: get the stream from the client and negotiate the endpoint. The tricky part when doing screenshare is to get the stream. The kurento-utils-js library will give you a little help on that, as you can create the `WebRtcPeer` object, in the client, indicating that you want to share your screen or a window. You just need to make sure that you

- have an extension installed to do screen-sharing in Chrome. In FF, it's enough to add the domain to the whitelist. Check [this](https://github.com/webrtc/samples/tree/master/src/content/extensions/desktopcapture) extension.
- pass a valid `sendSource` value (`screen` or `window`) in the options bag when creating the `kurentoUtils.WebRtcPeer` object
- have a `getScreenConstraints` method in your window object, as it will be used [here](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-utils-js/blob/master/lib/WebRtcPeer.js#L577). `getScreenConstraints` should return a valid set of constraints, depending on the browser. YOu can check an implementation of that function [here](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/blob/161ae6d036f1ab29c382bbed14425b55a8abc34e/Chrome-Extensions/Screen-Capturing.js/Screen-Capturing.js#L118)

I think that should be enough. We are doing screen sharing with the library, using our own `getScreenConstrains` and extension, and it works fine. Once you have that, doing screen sharing with the kurento-utils-js library is quite easy. Just need to pass the `sendSource` value when creating the peer like so

```
 var constraints = {
   audio: false,
   video: true
 }

 var options = {
   localVideo: videoInput, //if you want to see what you are sharing
   onicecandidate: onIceCandidate,
   mediaConstraints: constraints,
   sendSource: 'screen'
 }

 webRtcPeerScreencast = kurentoUtils.WebRtcPeer.WebRtcPeerSendrecv(options, function(error) {
   if (error) return onError(error) //You'll need to use whatever you use for handling errors

   this.generateOffer(onOffer)
 });
```

The value of `sendSource` is a string, and it depends on what you want to share

- `'screen'`: will let you share the whole screen. If you have more than one, you can choose which one to share
- `'window'`: lets you choose between all open windows
- `[ 'screen', 'window' ]`: WARNING! Only accepted by Chrome, this will let the user choose between full screens or windows.
- `'webcam'`: this is the default value of you don't specify anything here. Guess what'll happen ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @igracia, it was helpful. I fixed the problem by using [this hack](https://github.com/muaz-khan/getScreenId)

Comment: @Moroz_Grigory You are welcome! `getScreenId.js` is equivalent to our `getScreenConstraints` function :-)

Comment: I really appreciate this post helping me out get the required pieces of code for screen sharing....but when whenever I share my screen...my shared window is visible to me as local video, but the person who has joined the room still sees my webcam stream...

any idea why???

Comment: Further, how do I renegotiate my endpoint so that the others can see the shared screen?
@Moroz_Grigory how did u carry this out?

Comment: @Karthik you should double check mediaConstraints in your code to prevent sharing your screen (share your sources if it's possible).
About renegotiation:
You have to store all viewers/presenters. On connection you will ask your server about all presenters in room and then you'll connect to them using sessionID and local offer.